# On $-\frac{\zeta'(x)}{x\zeta(x)}$ and von Mangoldt function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, closed-form, riemann-zeta

I believe that it is possible show the following

> **Fact.** For real $x>e$ then $$-\frac{\zeta'(\log x)}{x\zeta(\log x)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^{\log x}},$$
>   where $\zeta(x)$ is the evaluation of the  **Riemann zeta function** in a real, and $\Lambda(n)$ is the **von Mangoldt function**.

When I tried use this fact I deduce the following, I don't know if it is useful or these computations were in the literature

> **Question.** Can you prove and justify for integers $k>1$ that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Lambda(n)\log\frac{e}{n}\int_{e^2}^{e^{k+1}}\frac{\log\zeta(\log x)}{n^{\log x}}dx$$ equals to 
>   $$(k-1)+e^2\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}\log\zeta(2)-e^{k+1}\frac{\zeta'(k+1)}{\zeta(k+1)}\log\zeta(k+1)?$$
>   **Thanks in advance.**

My computations were tedious but I believe that if there are no mistakes is the only way to solve it:

First I've deduced 
$$-1=\int_{e^2}^{e^3}\frac{\zeta(\log x)}{\zeta'(\log x)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^{\log x}}dx,$$
after I did the change $dv=\frac{\zeta(\log x)}{x\zeta'(\log x)}dx$ with $u=n^{-\log x}$, to get by** integration by parts** 
$$-1=-e^3\frac{\zeta'(3)}{\zeta(3)}\log\zeta(3)+e^2\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}\log\zeta(2)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Lambda(n)\log\frac{e}{n}\int_{e^2}^{e^3}\frac{\log\zeta(\log x)}{n^{\log x}}dx,$$
and thus we can write similar equations that telescoping get the result.

If there are mistakes please tell us.

Comment: You don't need to do tedious calculations. Since $x>e$ you have $\log(x)>1$ so you can prove your equality (without the $x$ at the denominator) taking the logarithm of the Euler's product of $\zeta(\log(x))$ and then differentiating.

Comment: Then feel free to add a more simple proof,  i understand your aproach.  Thanks @MarcoCantarini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $s=\log\left(x\right)
 $. Since $x>e
 $ we have $s>1
 $. So we can consider the Euler's product of the Zeta function $$\zeta\left(s\right)=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}\right)^{-1}
 $$ then taking the logarithm we have$$\log\left(\zeta\left(s\right)\right)=-\sum_{p}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}\right)
 $$ and differentiating $$\frac{\zeta'\left(s\right)}{\zeta\left(s\right)}=-\sum_{p}\frac{\log\left(p\right)}{p^{s}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}\right)^{-1}=-\sum_{p}\frac{\log\left(p\right)}{p^{s}}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{p^{sk}}
 $$ $$=-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\Lambda\left(n\right)}{n^{s}}
 $$ then $$\frac{\zeta'\left(\log\left(x\right)\right)}{\zeta\left(\log\left(x\right)\right)}=-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\Lambda\left(n\right)}{n^{\log\left(x\right)}}.
 $$ Note that the series start from $1$ but $\Lambda\left(1\right)=0
 $ so in some text you can find that the series starts from $2$.

Comment: Very thanks much for your answers, when your do it, I can say that it were good computations, yours, and the statement is right when you say it.

Comment: @user243301 You're welcome, I'm glad to help.